# Java inserting value to MySQL and returning values from MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating a employee login validation class where i can insert their to mysql database their information then for validation i'm trying to select only the password of the row.
here's my code:

```
     import java.sql.*;
        import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
        import java.sql.Connection;


    public class Employee 
    {

    private PreparedStatement statement;
    private Connection con;
    private String pass;
    public Employee()
    {   

    }
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String userID, String userPassword, String role )
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
            statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into employee(firstName, lastName, userID, " +
                    "password, role)values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");    

            statement.setString(1, firstName);
            statement.setString(2, lastName);
            statement.setString(3, userID);
            statement.setString(4, userPassword);
            statement.setString(5, role);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            con.close(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    public void setPassword(String userID)
    {
        try
        {
            statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE userID = ?");
            statement.setString(1, userID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                pass = rs.getString(4);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return pass;
    }


    }
and here is my main

        public class TestMain 
        {
        public static void main(String argsp[])
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setPassword("ecka12");  
    }
    }
```

i got a null pointer exception i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating object using: -

```
   Employee emp = new Employee();
```

In your 0-arg constructor you have not initialized your `connection`

```
public Employee() {

}
```

So, when you use `con` in `setPassword()` method, you will get `NullPointerException` : -

```
    // con is not initialized
    statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from employee WHERE userID = ?");
    statement.setString(1, userID);
```

**To correct this**, you need to 
move the below code to **`0-arg constructor`**.. And in your **other constructor**: - add **`this()`** as your first statement..

```
public Employee() {
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
     this(); // Initialize con..

     try {
        // You don't need to initialize your con here again..
        // Your remaining code.. 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the null pointer exception happens because you have an extra constructor public Employee() , con is not initializing therefore is causing a null pointer exception.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure the `employee table` is created before you are executing your code , because you have n't  created the table  in java code .

2.`Employee(String,,,,)` constructor have not used also ,because of this Connection did not get instantiated, you have closed the connection in constructor itself . so it may exist before searching for data in your table.